# Implementing the Karatsuba algorithm for multiplying polynomials

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I found the Karatsuba algorithm (divide-and-conquer with reduced multiplications of about half width) for multiplying polynomials as below:
[image: karatsuba]

[reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjfh4v4pf71AhVDneAKHUtxAxwQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.ust.hk%2Fmjg_lib%2FClasses%2FCOMP3711H_Fall14%2Flectures%2FDandC_Multiplication_Handout.pdf&usg=AOvVaw16c4PheGkXthM0LU8gMqT0)

and tried to implement it in Python. However, I do not understand the final recursive steps and U+[V+W]x**(n/2)+Zx**n at the end. So I am clueless as to how to correct my codes.

**Update:** I was able to successfully implement the below algorithm with the following code.
[image: karatsuba]

```
def PolynomialMult(n, p, q):
    # Multiply two polynomials
    def add(poly1, poly2):
        result = [0] * max(len(poly1), len(poly2))
        for i in range(len(result)):
            if i < len(poly1):
                result[i] += poly1[i]
            if i < len(poly2):
                result[i] += poly2[i]
        return result


    def increase_exponent(poly, n):
        return [0] * n + poly
    def multiply(p,q):
        n = len(p)
        m = n//2
        if len(p)==1: 
            res = []
            for i in range(n):
                res.append(p[i]*q[i])
            return res
        else:
            
            a0=p[0:m]
            a1=p[m:n]
            b0=q[0:m]
            b1=q[m:n]

            y=multiply(add(a0,a1),add(b0,b1))
            u=multiply(a0,b0)
            z=multiply(a1,b1)
            diff = add(y,[(-1 * x) for x in add(u,z)])
            add1 = add(u, increase_exponent(diff,m))
            add2 = increase_exponent(z,n)
            return add(add1, add2)
        
        
    return multiply(p,q)
```

But I am not able to make it within the time limit for two test cases.
How I can improve this?

Comment: It is from a pdf about multiplying polynomial that I've found online. I think it is using the karatsuba algorithm: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjfh4v4pf71AhVDneAKHUtxAxwQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.ust.hk%2Fmjg_lib%2FClasses%2FCOMP3711H_Fall14%2Flectures%2FDandC_Multiplication_Handout.pdf&usg=AOvVaw16c4PheGkXthM0LU8gMqT0

Comment: Thanks! I added a hyperlink. Can you check the update to see if it's the correct implementation?

Comment: `if it's the correct implementation?` There almost never is *the* correct implementation. And without a tight [specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings), it is hard to tell *correct*: Is `PolynomialMult()`/`multiply()` required to multiply polynomials of unlike degree? When that is documented (in the code), check out [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oops - there's a genuine error: Check the scaling with `increase_exponent(z,n)`. Note that PolyMulti2 shows exponent 2 n/2. And you compute `m` as `n//2`

Comment: (FWIW, I've tinkered some with *polynomial Karatsuba in Python*, starting with your code. Doesn't look convincing without NumPy. And not with it for [`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polymul(c1, c2)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polymul.html).) `[not making] it within the time limit for two test cases.` Referring to the task/challenge may increase chances for helpful answers, as may *test cases* or tagging [tag:karatsuba].

Comment: This implementation does not seem to provide the right answer. Using the example in the same presentation, where polynomial 1 is  `[1, 2, 3]` and polynomial 2 is `[3, 2, 2]`, we get as a result `[3, 8, 11, 4, 10, 6]` instead of `[3, 8, 15, 10, 6]`.

Besides that, the parameter `n` is not used in `PolynomialMult`, it is calculated there.

By the way, I'm facing the same error, i.e., getting the numbers spread and not added.

Comment: I found an implementation here: https://jovian.ai/mike-schmidek/python-divide-and-conquer-assignment